# Least Number of Unique Integers after K Removals Challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, dynamic-programming

The challenge is as follows:

```
Given an array of integers arr and an integer k. Find the least number of unique integers 
after removing exactly k elements.


Example 1:

Input: arr = [5,5,4], k = 1
Output: 1
Explanation: Remove the single 4, only 5 is left.
Example 2:
Input: arr = [4,3,1,1,3,3,2], k = 3
Output: 2
Explanation: Remove 4, 2 and either one of the two 1s or three 3s. 1 and 3 will be left.


Constraints:

1 <= arr.length <= 10^5
1 <= arr[i] <= 10^9
0 <= k <= arr.length
```

and I'm having difficulty understanding a person's solution to this. Would anyone be nice as to explain how his optimal solution works? This is a new challenge, in the recent leetcode contest, and there is no duplicate for it.

```py
    def findLeastNumOfUniqueInts3(self, A, K):
        count = collections.Counter(A)
        items = list(count.items())
        items.sort(key=lambda e: e[1])
        ans = len(items)
        for i, (_, x) in enumerate(items):
            if K >= x:
                K -= x
                ans -= 1
        return ans
```

Comment: Try putting `print` statements in various places in the code, then you will be able to see what it is doing.

Comment: Just sorting by frequency from lowest to highest and then removing first k items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the person made individual counts of numbers using Counter(collections)

Let's say, your input list is [4,3,1,1,3,3,2], then individual counts of that list become:

```
number     count
  4    ->    1
  3    ->    3
  1    ->    2
  2    ->    1
```

After sorting:

```
number     count
  4    ->    1
  2    ->    1
  1    ->    2
  3    ->    3
```

Now you can remove K numbers, to get the least number of unique numbers, the intuition here is, we first start with least occurring numbers, so that we can remove max unique numbers, which results with least unique numbers (which is desired).

Now he traversed the sorted list of item counts and deduced the value of K if the count of the current item is less than K, he traversed until K==0 or we traversed the whole list. If an items count it less than K, we can increment the count and can deduce it from the length of unique numbers from the given list.

Here's my solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def uns(A, K):
    icounts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
    for x in A:
        icounts[x]+=1

    counts = [icounts[i] for i in icounts]
    counts = sorted(counts)

    rem = 0
    for x in counts:
        if K>=x:
            rem+=1
            K-=x
        if(K==0):
            break

    return len(counts)-rem
print(uns([4,3,1,1,3,3,2],3))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Hope you understand my explanation.